# Allow user1 to "su - user2" without password

Tags: users, password, authentication, pam

I need to allow user `martin` to switch to user `martin-test` without password

```
su - martin-test
```

I think this can be configured in `/etc/pam.d/su`. There are already some lines in that file which can be uncommented. However, I don't like the idea of adding user `martin` to group `wheel`. I don't want to give `martin` any more privileges than to be able to switch to `martin-test`. I also do not want to use `sudo`.

What would be the best way to do it, while keeping the privileges of user `martin` minimal?

Comment: This is easier to do with `sudo` eg `sudo -u martin-test -i`. Is there a reason you are asking specifically about `su`?

Comment: I don't want to install `sudo` just because of this (I don't normally use `sudo` and I don't particularly like it). And I think using `pam` is cleaner and more transparent way to do it.

Comment: @drewbenn I need a solution independent of `ssh`. I cannot rely on `ssh` server to be running at all times. But otherwise, that would be an interesting solution.

Comment: @MartinVegter As you can see from the script answer, doing this through some sort of pam mechanism is very ugly. Really this is exactly what `sudo` was meant for. Aside from not normally using it, what are the objections?

Comment: downvoted because you refuse to use `sudo`, even though it is designed for exactly this kind of situation, and you have been unable to produce a reason for not using it that's grounded in a technical evaluation. in addition, neither your bounty description nor your question nor your comments say _anything_ about what is wrong with the current answer.

Comment: If a clean solution is possible with `pam`, I would prefer that over `sudo`. If `sudo` is the only possibility, than that is fine as well. My objections to `sudo` are mostly ideological: I don't like the idea of user doing administration with `sudo foo`. When I need to do administration, I log in as root. Otherwise I log in as user, These two distinct roles should not be mixed. Also, I already have `pam` infrastructure installed. I don't want to install another `setuid` program which can possibly introduce security bugs.

Comment: @MartinVegter You don't have to do `sudo foo` for specific commands. Sudo has `sudo -s` which will launch a shell. sudo is a very common utility meaning it's security has been thoroughly vetted, **far more** than some pam trickery will be. I would also argue that getting a root shell for tasks is much more insecure than launching specific commands. When you launch a shell, you run **everything** as root. If any one of those things (such as a simple `ls`) has a security vulnerability, then you've just opened a security hole.

Comment: @MartinVegter there you go, can't get cleaner than that without sudo. Also, I agree with Patrick regarding pam trickery security over sudo.

Comment: Really, `sudo` uses "pam trickery" to manage authentication (as `/etc/pam.d/sudo` exists), so it sure ain't more secure or thoroughly vetted than `pam`. `sudo` is just a shim with suid bit reading config files (so it's possible to configure and perform trickery with it; as opposed to `su`) -- and using `pam`. `su` and `sudo` are also [basically the same thing](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/sudo-vs-su/): _"The primary difference between the two is the password they require: while 'sudo' requires current user's password, 'su' requires you to enter the root user password."_

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Add the following lines underneath the `pam_rootok.so` line in your `/etc/pam.d/su`:

```
auth  [success=ignore default=1] pam_succeed_if.so user = martin-test
auth  sufficient                 pam_succeed_if.so use_uid user = martin
```

These lines perform checks using the [`pam_succeed_if.so`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_succeed_if) module. See also the [Linux-PAM configuration file syntax](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/sag-configuration-file.html) to learn more about the `auth` lines.

- The first line checks whether the *target user* is `martin-test`. If it is nothing happens (`success=ignore`) and we can continue on the next line to check the *current user*. If it is not, the next line will be skipped (`default=1`) and we can continue on subsequent lines with the usual authentication steps.
- The second line checks whether the current user is `martin` or not, if it is then the system considers the authentication process as successful and returns (`sufficient`), if it is not, nothing happens and we continue on subsequent lines with the usual authentication steps.

You can also restrict `su` to a group, here the group `allowedpeople` can `su` without a password:

```
auth sufficient pam_succeed_if.so use_uid user ingroup allowedpeople
```

Comment: If you want to authorize if they are in a certain group:
auth sufficient pam_succeed_if.so user ingroup GROUP

Comment: @gnp Super Thanks!! Working on iCinga with nrpe, have to execute some command as different user!! Helped lot!!!!!! Thanks!!!!!

Comment: @GnP Please help me on http://askubuntu.com/questions/821793/users-su-without-password-with-pam-su-authentication

Comment: It would be nice to add info on how to apply the changes as well.

Comment: @Kyslik what do you mean? The instructions on how to edit the necessary files are in the answer ...

Comment: Dont you need to restart some kind of service?

Comment: @Kyslik oh right. Not in this case where the changes apply only to `su`. (There may be other instances of pam changes that require restarting a service)

Comment: I came up with two lines: `auth [success=ok default=1] pam_succeed_if.so use_uid user in martin:martin-test` and `auth [success=done default=ok] pam_succeed_if.so user in martin:martin-test` to also allow _martin-test_ to switch to _martin_

Comment: I'm getting `su: pam_start: system error` (on mac os x)

Answer (score 14):

If you don't want to change groups or use `sudo`, use a pam module called `pam_exec` to execute external scripts in a pam stage.

Add a line in your `/etc/pam.d/su` after the `pam_rootok.so` line:

```
auth       sufficient pam_exec.so quiet /path/to/script
```

`/path/to/script` has the permissions 755 (rwxr-xr-x) and the following content:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$PAM_TYPE" == "auth" ] && \
[ "$PAM_USER" == "martin-test" ] && \
[ "$PAM_RUSER" == "martin" ]; then
  exit 0
else
  exit 1
fi
```

So this script exits with success if `su`:

- is called in context of authentication,
- the calling user is `martin` and
- the user to authenticate is `martin-test`.

See:

```
martin@host:~$ su - martin-test
martin-test@host:~$ exit
martin@host:~$ su - otheruser
Password: ****
otheruser@host:~$
```

Comment: pam_access can be used to provide similar functionality, without relying on a script.  (this is what pam_access was made to do)

Comment: @jsbillings Would you make that (with some details) another answer?

Comment: how would I need to modify my `/etc/pam.d/su` to make use of `pam_access` for my situation?

Comment: @jsbillings Actually `pam_access` can't do this. When `su` is going through the pam stack, it's doing so as the user you're changing to, not the user you're changing from. So if you add a rule such as `+ : martin : ALL`, it will allow **anyone** changing **to** `martin`. Even if you change `martin` to `martin-test`, it will still let anyone do it. You need to analyze both the user you're coming from, and the user you're changing to. Really, this is exactly what `sudo` is for...

Answer (score 9):

**This might be the possible best way.**

`su` is not meant to do that -- `sudo` is.

**Open** `/etc/sudoers.d/custom` and write the following:

`user-a ALL=(user-b:user-b) NOPASSWD:ALL`

**This means**: whenever user-a executes `sudo -u user-b`, let him go without asking for the password.

**Another way**

```
youruserid ALL = (username) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

with `visudo` and then `sudo -u username bash` is like `su - username`

Comment: What if you don't have root access? I want to change from my user to another non-root user.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have access to the root account, but have the password of the user you want to use to run a command, you can do the following.

- This will ask you the toto's password : su - toto -c whoami

  This will not : ssh toto@localhost whoami

Just install your public key in authorized_keys of toto

Comment: Thoughtful answer.. However, the command someone wanna try running is already on the machine. So there is no point ssh'ing to the same server.

Answer (score -1):

My simple solution is:

```
sudo login -f martin-test
```

If you want to avoid sudo at all cost, I think it should be possible to put this in a script:

1. owned by root and with root privileges (using the [setuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) flag)
2. executable by everybody, also without any sudo.

However, I can't figure out the `chown root` and `chmod +s ToTest.sh` bits, to make this actually work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo howdy, I am $(whoami)
sudo login -f martin-test
```

I still runs as my normal user, as the echo tells me. And it still requires sudo password. If it was running as root, one could do away with the `sudo` in the last line...

Comment: The setuid flag on a shell (or any other script) script won't work in Linux and for good reasons. Notice that the above script with a working suid flag would immediately be a trap: It engages bash via "env" (quite self-defeatingly, because if you assume you don't know where `bash` is, why do you assume you know where `env` is or whether it even exists?). But in the end, you don't know what `bash` this will be exactly. It could come from the invoking user's directory and have been compiled a minute earlier from his source code. You see where I'm going? Or the user could override `whoami`...

Comment: My brain is currently too far away from these issues to fully grasp, but still thanx for the detailed explanations.