# Allow multiple users to "su" to multiple other users without password

Tags: users, su, pam

This is similar to this question:

[Allow user1 to "su - user2" without password](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/113754/allow-user1-to-su-user2-without-password)

However, the solution only work for multiple users accessing "su"ing ONE user.

```
#works fine :) 2 or more users accessing 1 user
auth       [success=ignore default=1] pam_succeed_if.so user = user1
auth       sufficient   pam_succeed_if.so use_uid user = user2
auth       sufficient   pam_succeed_if.so use_uid user = user3
```

If I try to go n-users to n-users:

```
#dont work :(
auth       [success=ignore default=1] pam_succeed_if.so user = user1
auth       sufficient   pam_succeed_if.so use_uid user = user2
auth       sufficient   pam_succeed_if.so use_uid user = user3

auth       [success=ignore default=1] pam_succeed_if.so user = user4
auth       sufficient   pam_succeed_if.so use_uid user = user2
auth       sufficient   pam_succeed_if.so use_uid user = user3
```

I get PAM errors or get asked for input the password.

Comment: sudo is designed exactly for this...

Comment: I'm working in a environment that sadly I do not have access to changing 'sudoers' file. However I do have root user access. So I'm trying to workaround with passwordless "su".

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, the code `[success=ignore default=1]` means that if the module returns anything other than success, skip 1 module.  Perhaps you need to skip 2 to get to the next `pam_succeed_if` ?

Comment: I tried using [success=ignore default=2] but didn't work. I get the message "could not set PAM credentials" everytime for the first auth declaration. The second always works, seems like it is overwriting the other one.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the auth order, like this:

```
auth       [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so user = user1
auth       [success=ignore default=1] pam_succeed_if.so user = user4
auth       sufficient   pam_succeed_if.so use_uid user in user2:user3
```

Comment: Welcome on the Unix SE! Help in pam things is always very useful. However, writing just code/script/config snippets reduces the mean quality of the site. Please explain, what did you change and why.

Comment: this solved it for me, allowing su without password into user1 and user4

Answer (score 0):

I am accomplishing it using `pam_exec.so` instead of `pam_succeedif.so`.

In `/etc/pam.d/su` immediately after `pam_rootok.so`:

```
auth  sufficient             pam_exec.so quiet /etc/pam.d/check_user.sh
```

In `/etc/pam.d/check_user.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
[[ -z $PAM_RUSER ]] && PAM_RUSER=$PAM_USER # under some circumstances pam_exec.so does not pass PAM_RUSER to the script
[[ "$PAM_TYPE" == "auth" ]] || exit 1
case "$PAM_RUSER" in
  user1)        USERS="user1 user2" ; ;;
  user3)        USERS="user3 user4" ; ;;
  *)            exit 1 ; ;;
esac
[[ "$USERS" =~ "$PAM_USER" ]]
```