# How to ensure I know my password?

Tags: ubuntu, password, authentication

I am connecting to machine via ssh key and have sudo rights. How can I check that username password I know is correct?

`/etc/shadow` doesnt' contain me.

What else can be done?

Comment: Rename your local SSH key temporarily and try to login with your password. And if your system doesn't allow password-based authentification why should you worry?

Comment: @xenoid The question is "what else can be done?" and your comment looks like an answer.

Answer (score 6):

Invoke `passwd`. You should be asked your current password; provide the password you know.

Wrong password will make the command fail immediately. Correct password will allow you to set a new password. Set a new password by typing it twice or deliberately type two different strings to leave the password unchanged.

---

Does `su "$USER"` ask for a password? [It may not](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/113754/108618) but if it does, provide the password you know.

Wrong password will make the command fail with `Authentication failure`. Correct password will give you a shell (exit it with `exit`).

Answer (score 2):

You might be using directory services and not be using a local account. In that case you won't find an entry in `/etc/shadow`.

Check `passwd` entry in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` for that.

It is possible to skip key authentication with SSH using

```
ssh -o "PubkeyAuthentication=no" <host>
```

This way you can try to login with your password*

*) if other authentication mechanisms are not in place. Otherwise you can use `-o "PreferredAuthentications=password"` to force password authentication